# How to continue Observable chain on condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Say I want to send a comment in a chat application, but only if some variable is true (`shouldSendMessage`), what is the best way to achieve this with Observables?

This works, but is ugly:

```
Observable.of({})
  .takeWhile(() => this.state.alive)
  .flatMap(() => this.state.shouldSendMessage ? Observable.of({}) : Observable.empty())
  .flatMap(() => this.Chat.sendMessage(myMessage))
  .subscribe(x => {
    //Do something after message sent successfully
  });
```

The two lines that I would like to do better are:

```
Observable.of({})
```

and

```
.flatMap(() => this.state.shouldSendMessage ? Observable.of({}) : Observable.empty())
```

Note: The `this.state.alive` is so that a separate variable does not need to be stored for the subscription and unsubscribed to

Comment: Why are you creating this observable chain like this? Everything prior to the service call doesn't need to be done with observables and is the cause of the code you don't like.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I don't know yet whether I want `sendMessage` to be called yet, as it depends on other conditions

Comment: Your promise chain will run at most once with what you have (since the start of your chain emits a single value). You could have all of the logic prior to send logic not done in an observable

Comment: Also, instead of your first `flatMap`, you would actually want to use a `filter` (e.g. `filter(() => this.state.shouldSendMessage)`) if you actually needed a chain like this

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Thanks for the reply. What would you suggest would be the best way to only run some method if a check passes? I cant put the `sendMessage` first as it will always run. What should come before it in the chain? (Without just using an `if condition`

Comment: In an observable steam you would use a filter (like I showed previously), but with the code you have above, you unnecessarily created a stream in order to make a web call. You just need to use normal `if` logic like: `if (this.state.alive && this.state.shouldSendMessage) { this.Chat.sendMessage(myMessage).subscribe(...); }`

Comment: Won't you create a new subscription each time that action takes place? Say i need some id to be present in the url before you are allowed to send a message, so we do the check `if (somethingIsTrue)` and now call `sendMessage` with a subscribe again. Every time you send a new message, will it create a new subscription?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170577/discussion-between-daniel-w-strimpel-and-tic).

Answer (score 0):

When `this.state.alive` and `this.stateShouldSendMessage` are simple values and not some streams, you don't need to handle them asynchronously:

```
...
send: myMessage => {
  if (!this.state.alive || !this.stateShouldSendMessage) {
    return Observable.empty();
  }
  return this.Chat.sendMessage(myMessage); 
},
...
```

When e.g. `this.state.alive` is an Observable (which could make sense) you could do something like this: `alive$.filter(alive => alive === true).mergeMapTo(this.Chat.sendMessage(myMessage))` to achieve the same effect.